# Calling a parent classes method vs. calling a static method

Tags: php, oop

To call a parent class (it has been instantiated) method I use

```
parent_class::method();  //tested it works
```

to call a method with in the instantiated class I am in I use

```
$this->method();  //tested it works
```

However if I call a static method from any class I use

```
parent_class::static_method();  //tested it works
```

I guess this makes since b.c. there is only one copy of a method per class, whether it is instantiated or not?

Can some one validate or provide insight to this. I just want to verify that the call method is the same for both static methods from any class and calls to a parent classes method.

Seems a bit strange.

Comment: question not clear ! more detail please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct. Not exactly sure what your question is. If you wanted to call a static method defined in the child from within the child, you could use `self::static_method()` or `$this->static_method()`. Either would work.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't use `->` for anything but instance methods.

Comment: @BoltClock you don't, but since static classes *can* be instantiated, `self::myStaticMethod();` and `$this->myStaticMethod()` will both execute just fine from within the class where the static method resides. Try it :)